# Cannot update subitems ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, subitem

I have two `ListBox`es.  One `ListBox` displays some items.  Each item has a list of subitems.  The second `ListBox` displays the subitems of the current item in the first `ListBox`.  A typical item/subitem scenario.  When I add a value to the subitem list, I cannot get the second `ListBox` to update.  How can I force the second `ListBox` to update my subitems?

My simplified XAML and view model are below.  Note that my view model inherits from Prism's `BindableBase`.  In my view model I have a method to add a value to the subitems list and update the `Items` property with `RaisePropertyChanged`.

```xml
<ListBox Name="Items" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>            
                <Label Content="{Binding ItemValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />            
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<ListBox Name="SubItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Items.CurrentItem.SubItems}" >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

```cs
class Item
{
    public int ItemValue { get; set; }
    public List<int> SubItems { get; set; }
}

class MyViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();        

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        List<Item> myItems = new List<Item>() {  /* a bunch of items */ };

        _items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(myItems);
        Items = new ListCollectionView(_items);
    }

    public ICollectionView Items { get; private set; }

    private void AddNewSubItem(object obj)
    {
        Item currentItem = Items.CurrentItem as Item;

        currentItem.SubItems.Add(123);            

        RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
    }
}
```

Comment: `<ListBox Name="SubItems" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.SubItems, ElementName=Items}" >`

Comment: This did not work.  Values are added to SubItems just fine, just not updating ListBox.  I tried Items.InvalidateVisual and Items.UpdateLayout - did not work either.

Comment: Is Item.SubItems an ObservableCollection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your `Item` type contains a `List<int>`, which does not notify on collection changes, because it does not implement the [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=net-5.0) interface. Consequently, bindings do not get notified to update their values in the user interface when the collection is modified. Using a collection that implements this interface, e.g. an [`ObservableCollection<int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0) will solve the issue.

By the way, the same applies to `ItemValue` and `SubItems` properties as well with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Both properties have setters, which means they can be reassigned, but the bindings will not get notified then either. Since you use `BindableBase`, you can use the `SetProperty` method with backing fields to automatically raise the [`PropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=net-5.0) event when a property is set.

```
public class Item : BindableBase
{
   private int _itemValue;
   private ObservableCollection<int> _subItems;

   public int ItemValue
   {
      get => _itemValue;
      set => SetProperty(ref _itemValue, value);
   }

   public ObservableCollection<int> SubItems
   {
      get => _subItems;
      set => SetProperty(ref _subItems, value);
   }
}
```

A remark about your project. What you try to do is a [master-detail view for hierarchical data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-use-the-master-detail-pattern-with-hierarchical-data?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). Since you already expose an `ICollectionView`, you do not have to use the `CurrentItem` explicitly.

> When the source is a collection view, the current item can be specified with a slash (/). For example, the clause Path=/ sets the binding to the current item in the view. When the source is a collection, this syntax specifies the current item of the default collection view.

There is a [special binding syntax, where you can use a `/`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#binding-path-syntax) to indicate the current item, e.g.:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Name="SubItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Items/SubItems}">
```

Additionally a few remarks about your view model code.

- The `_items` field initializer is useless, as you reassign the field in the constructor anyway.
- If you only use the collection view and not `_items`, you can use a local variable in the constructor.
- The private setter of `Items` is not used, you can remove it.
- Cast the `Items.CurrentItem` directly to `Item` to get an invalid cast exception that is more specific that the null reference exception that you would get later when accessing the value from using `as` and getting `null`. If you expect that the value could be something else than an `Item`, you could check for `null` after `as` or use pattern matching to handle both cases, success and error (`CurrentItem` is not of type `Item`) appropriately.

Comment: Many thanks!  A very complete answer.  I also greatly appreciate the comments regarding other parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Item
{
    public int ItemValue { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<int> SubItems { get;}
      = new ObservableCollection<int>();
}
```

```
class MyViewModel : BindableBase
{
    publc ObservableCollection<Item> Items {get;}
        = new ObservableCollection<Item>();        

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        List<Item> myItems = new List<Item>() {  /* a bunch of items */ };

        myItems.ForEach(item => Items.Add(item));
    }

    private Item _currentItem;
    private Item CurrentItem
    {
       get => _currentItem;
       set
       {
          if(Equals(_currentItem, value))
            return;

          _currentItem = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentItem));
       }
    }

    private void AddNewSubItem(object obj)
    {
        CurrentItem.SubItems.Add(123);            
    }
}
```

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}">
  ********
  ********
</ListBox>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentItem.SubItems}" >
  ********
  ********
</ListBox>
```